# Find the Taylor series for $\sqrt{x}$ centered at 16

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Taylor series for $\sqrt{x}$ centered at $a=16$.

I begin by finding some derivatives so that i can work out a formula for the $n_{th}$ derivative as the Taylor series for a function is given by:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{n}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

I obtained the following for the first four derivatives:

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$f^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{-1}{2}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$f^3(x)=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{-1}{2}.\frac{-3}{2}x^{-\frac{5}{2}}$$
$$f^4(x)=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{-1}{2}.\frac{-3}{2}.\frac{-5}{2}x^{-\frac{7}{2}}$$

from this i have determined that successive terms alternate in signs beginning with a positive, so i might say that $f^n(a) = (-1)^{n+1}$ and checking for n=1 results in a positive, n=2 negative etc. Next, it is easily seen that success derivatives have the pattern $\frac{1}{2^n}$, the powers of x, $\text{}$ $x^{\frac{-2n+1}{2}}$

I am having difficulty obtaining a pattern for $1.1.3.5.7...$
I notice that sometimes in these problems you can only get a pattern for the derivatives from say n=2, or n=3. My instinct says knock off the first derivative and obtain a pattern for n=2 onwards then we have $1.3.5.7 $
I've tried a couple of things using $Tn=a+(n-1)d$ to get the pattern but i'm not having much luck. Could someone provide me some tips on how to determine this pattern and also how to know when you have to 'knock off a term', say only take a pattern from n=2?

**edit**

In order to determine the pattern you can do the following. given a sequence that starts at n=2 and is $3.7.11...$ for example. Take the difference between the terms, so 4. then multiply by n: $4n$ now substitute values of n to see what this gives and compare to what is expected. so for $n=2$, $4(2)=8$ but we want $3$ so we need to subtract 5. Likewise for n=3, $4(3)=12$ but we want 7 so subtracting 5 will give 7. Hence the pattern is $3.7.11...(4n-5)$

Comment: $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n-3)$ IS the pattern. Can't simplify it much! You can write it as a quotient involving factorials and powers of two, if you prefer that.

Comment: Thank you @Jyrki Lahtonen, this is what i'm looking for. Would you mind explaining what your process was for getting that (2n-3)? It seems obvious to me now by inspection but i often get stuck with these sorts of patterns and can't see it.

Comment: I see it now. The 2n-3 can be obtained by taking the difference between the numbers, so 2n but then seeing for n=3 we should get 3 but 2(3) = 6 so we need to subtract 3. for n=4 we should get 5 but 2(4) = 8 so again subtract 3. Hence 2n-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by the extended binomial theorem, for $|z|\leq 1$,
$$\sqrt{1+z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{n}z^n$$
where $\binom{1/2}{0}=1$,  $\binom{1/2}{1}=1/2$ and for $n>1$,
$$\binom{1/2}{n}=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right)=
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n-3))}{n!2^n}
=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n-1)4^n}.$$
Hence for $|x-16|\leq 16$,
$$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{16+(x-16)}=4\sqrt{1-\frac{(x-16)}{16}}=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{1/2}{n}}{16^n}(x-16)^n\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n-1)4^{3n-1}}(x-16)^n.$$